# Installing Vundle: "fatal: could not create leading directories"

Tags: macos, plugin-vundle

Following the instructions on the [Vundle GitHub page](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim), entering

```
git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

in terminal on MacOS gives

> fatal: could not create leading directories of '/Users/carlo/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim': Not a directory

I think it has to do with the `/.vim` directory being hidden, but I couldn't get past this.

Comment: That looks like a permission issue: does `~/.vim/bundle` exists? If it exists what are its permissions?

Comment: I don't think it does, but when I try to create it with `mkdir /.vim/bundle` I get `mkdir: /Users/carlo/.vim: Not a directory`

Comment: You get an error because you don't have a vim directory. If you can execute `mkdir -p ~/.vim/bundle` with no error, you should be able to clone your repo.

Comment: I do have a `/.vim` directory though (it comes up when I execute `ls -a`). That's what's puzzling me.

Answer (score 1):

You said when you run `ls -a`, you see `/.vim`.  First, make sure you have it in your home directory, try running `cd` and then `ls -a`.  `/.vim` is not `~/.vim`, and you really shouldn't be making folders like that in the `/` directory (which is computer-wide and has special permissions).

You should be making your dir with this:

```
mkdir ~/.vim/bundle
```

Note the `~` at the start.

If this fails with another "not a directory", run

```
mkdir ~/.vim
```

and then run the first command again.

After this, you can run `git clone` successfully.  For what it's worth, you don't need to specify the path, just `cd ~/.vim/bundle` and run `git clone <url>`.  It will automatically name it the same as the git repo, which is "Vundle".

Comment: `git clone` makes all intermediate directories. For example I just tried `git clone git@github.com:Carpetsmoker/st.git ~/this/does/not/exist/yet` and that worked without problems. As far as I know, `git` has always done this; but perhaps (very) old versions don't?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Doesn't work for me, are you using OS X?

Comment: Linux master race of course :-) Git version 2.15.1

Comment: So running `mkdir ~/.vim/bundle` gives "not a directory", but `mkdir ~/.vim` gives "file exists" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Do you have a *file* named `~/.vim` @Fibonacho? What does `ls -l ~/.vim` say?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker it seems that was indeed the problem. Thanks for your time!